# Xcode 6 deleting App Group

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I need to delete some of the **`App Groups`** I created in order to share information between the App and it's Today Extension.

Does anybody know how to delete an **`App Group`** created in the Capabilities section of **`Xcode`**, in **`App Groups`**?

Comment: Turn off Group from Capabilities Tab.

Answer (score 36):

Here are the following steps to delete the App Groups:

1. Login to [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) with your developer account.
2. On the Dashboard Under **Dev Centre** Select iOS[image]
3. Select **Certificates,Identifiers and Profiles** under iOS Developer Program.[image]

4.Select **Identifiers** under iOS Apps.

[image]

5. Select **App Groups** under Identifiers.

[image]

6. Then you find the List of all App Groups you have created,Select the one you want to delete,there you find the option to delete the **App Group.**

Enjoy......:)

**[UPDATE]**

Latest Apple Developer portal moved it to the **top right** of the **Identifiers** page
[image]