# Is developer account necessary to turn on capabilities in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to pass data between my iPhone and Apple Watch apps but I'm not able to turn ON App Groups in Capabilities since it shows that I need to be enrolled in a developer program. But in the tutorial I follow, it works perfect. I need to run the app in Simulator only. Also my instructor told me that there's no need for a developer account. What could possibly be the issue? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try disabling code signing from project settings -> build settings for selected build configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it Is Necessary to have a Developer account to enable the Capabilities as it contains all the records for the enabled capabilities over developer account.For example you can see the **App Group** Capabilities stored in developer account. Refer to [This Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117252/xcode-6-deleting-app-group/29117618#29117618).